# This is one of the sample complicated query I am using to pull data from salesforce using ADF but some don't work

Tags: apex, soql, azure

Examples of queries which don't work

1. `Select TYPEOF Owner WHEN User THEN FederationIdentifier, Title, Department END, VFS_External_Id__c   From genesis__Applications__c`
2. `SELECT TYPEOF Owner WHEN User THEN Username, Firstname, Alias, LastName, Fax, Phone, Email, Street, PostalCode, City, Country, LanguageLocaleKey END FROM genesis__Applications__c`

These queries throw out an error on adf as follows:

> ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][Salesforce] (120) SOQL_FIRST mode prepare failure:
> SOQL error: [Microsoft][SQLEngine] (31480) syntax error near 'Select
> TYPEOF Owner<<< ??? >>> WHEN User THEN FederationIdentifier, Title, Department END, VFS_External_Id__c
> From genesis__Applications__c'.

> SQL error: [Microsoft][SQLEngine] (31480) syntax error near 'Select
> TYPEOF Owner WHEN<<< ??? >>> User THEN FederationIdentifier, Title, Department END, VFS_External_Id__c
> From genesis__Applications__c'.

What is the best approach in this case can these queries be simplified or is this a show stopper?
Note: Both of these queries work perfectly on Salesforce.

Comment: It's always a good idea to use the full form first, then introduce the abbreviation. That's even more important to do when you're talking about industry-specific jargon (wanna take a guess at what NPA, POP, and DID mean without me giving any hints?) or things off of the Salesforce platform. In this case, it appears that "ADF" is "Azure Data Factory".

Answer (score 2):

If you need to get related data from a polymorphic relationship field, then using `TYPEOF` is really your only option (short of only querying the relationship field itself and doing additional processing elsewhere so you can tie the user Id from `OwnerId` to an actual `User` record).

Doing some more searching revealed [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69349279/does-azure-data-factorys-salesforce-connector-support-the-typeof-keyword-in-soq) which points out that Salesforce's documentation says that `TYPEOF` is not supported via the bulk api.

Looks like Azure switches to the Bulk API at some undefined point, so hopefully the volume of records you're working with isn't too large.

You'll also probably need to explicitly set the api version that Azure Data Factory is using, since they may be defaulting to either 45.0 or 40.0 and `TYPEOF` was introduced in api version 46.0 (and we're pretty close to the release of api version 59.0 at time of writing)